# Is it possible to run Logback for a single webapp in Tomcat?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, slf4j, logback

I'd like to configure one of my webapps to entirely use SLF4J over Logback for logging. I'd like to leave the rest of Tomcat alone, I'd just like to ensure that all logging done in my webapp (by Spring, Hibernate, EhCache, etc.) are done through SLF4J through my Logback context for the webapp and not through Tomcat's default (JUL?) logging system.

I've noticed that multiple libraries are "missing" SLF4J when logging which normally would use SLF4J in any other circumstance. EhCache *is* using SLF4J, but Spring and some other libraries are using JUL and ignoring SLF4J:

```
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:45 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Fri Jul 13 11:25:45 PDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:45 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
...
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:45 AM org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Initializing EHCache CacheManager
11:25:45.795 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory - Configuring ehcache from InputStream
11:25:45.808 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler - Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
11:25:45.808 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler - Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
11:25:45.809 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.DiskStoreConfiguration - Disk Store Path: /tmp/ehcache
11:25:45.828 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper - No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
11:25:45.847 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
11:25:45.847 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
11:25:45.847 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
11:25:45.849 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
11:25:45.849 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
11:25:45.849 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
11:25:45.866 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.NotifyingMemoryStore for encodingJobDetails.cache
11:25:45.869 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache - Initialised cache: encodingJobDetails.cache
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:45 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/check/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.tkassembled.model.JobDetails com.tkassembled.controller.JobController.check(java.lang.String)
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:45 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/submit],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.tkassembled.model.JobTicket com.tkassembled.controller.JobController.submit(com.tkassembled.model.Job)
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:46 AM org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxbContextFromContextPath
INFO: Creating JAXBContext with context path [com.tkassembled.model]
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:46 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 939 ms
Jul 13, 2012 11:25:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"]
```

How can I make all SLF4J-capable libraries use Logback? Why is EhCache using it properly and everything else isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLF4J provides artifacts for routing logs from log4j, j.u.l. and commons-logging to SLF4J. See 
the document entitled [Bridging legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) for details.

Spring uses commons logging. Fortunately, SLF4J provides a perfect binary replacement for commons-logging called [jcl-over-slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jclOverSLF4J). You just need to replace the commons-logging dependency with jcl-over-slf4j. This is explained in the [SLF4J FAQ](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL).